# Rails 3 redirect a public file to an external path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.3, I'm trying to redirect a file in my public folder to an external URL.

This is because this file is going to be managed by another party.

I'm unsure how to accomplish this.

But I need for a file like this:

```
mysite.com/publicfile.html
```

to redirect to:

```
someoneelsessite.com/publicfile.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a route:

```
get 'publicfile.html', to: redirect('https://someonelsesste.com/publicfile.html')
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Make sure you DON'T have that `publicfile.html` file on your public folder, or it will be served before reaching the router.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Intuitively, you would think you need the file to exist. But you do not. That was the trick, thank you.